# Default .snippet Files

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, refactoring, code-snippets

I am trying to edit the default snippet file that Microsoft created, where if you type `"+= [Event Handler Method]; + TAB"` it creates the stub for that event handler.

Currently, the snippet creates a void method for that event handler. I want it to create a private void method.

After editing Microsoft file `(C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC#\Snippets\1033\Refactoring\EventStub - Field.snippet)` to either cause it to crash or add `"private"` to the method, it will either add private once and then work the default way every other time after, not work at all and then work the default way every other time after, or just continue to work as if the file had never been changed.

Is there any explaination to, one, why this edited file will only work with the change once/doesn't seem to be changed? and two, how to edit this snippet file if there is a way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file needed to be edited is C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC#\Snippets\1033\Refactoring\ MethodStub or whatever pathway your default snippets are in.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CodeSnippets  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
    <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
        <Header>
            <Title>Method Stub - Body</Title>
            <Description>Snippet for generating method stub with a body</Description>
            <Author>Microsoft Corporation</Author>
            <SnippetTypes>
                <SnippetType>Refactoring</SnippetType>
            </SnippetTypes>
        </Header>
        <Snippet>
            <Declarations>
                <Literal Editable="true">
                    <ID>signature</ID>
                    <Default>signature</Default>
                </Literal>
                <Literal>
                    <ID>Exception</ID>
                    <Function>SimpleTypeName(global::System.NotImplementedException)</Function>
                </Literal>
            </Declarations>
            <Code Language="csharp">
                <![CDATA[private $signature$
{
    $end$throw new $Exception$();
}]]>
            </Code>
        </Snippet>
    </CodeSnippet>
</CodeSnippets>
```